# nircmd screen capture is smaller than actual resolution of the screen

Tags: resolution, screenshot, high-dpi, nircmd

I am taking a screenshot using NirCmd `savescreenshot`. The result screenshot is smaller than the actual resolution of the my screen. My screen resolution is 1920 x 1080.

When I tried [this link](https://www.nirsoft.net/show_my_ip_address.php), it gives screen width is 1280, screen height is 720.

I think NirCmd is capturing 1280 x 720, not 1920 x 1080. Can I make anything in NirCmd to solve the issue and for the screen capture to be full?

I used `nircmd.exe setdisplay 1920 1080 32`, but still the capture is small

Yes, I have a scale factor of 150%

Comment: Do you have in *Settings > System > Display* have a scale factor of 150% ?

Comment: yes ,  scale factor  150% is there , what to do , shall I remove it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NirCmd is correctly doing the capture of the pixels of the screen
*as reported by Windows*.

You have defined for the screen a scale factor of 150%. This means that it is
scaled as if each pixel was 1.5 times larger, so that in effect
there are 1.5 times less pixels on the screen.

NirCmd is only calling Windows to get the pixels, and has no knowledge of the
status of the hardware pixels. Even if it did, capturing the physical pixels
would give a twisted image at best.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're using an older version of nircmd. From the change log you can see ***since version 2.82 onward it can take the full desktop screenshot*** without problem

> | Date | Version | Description |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 22/03/2019 | 2.82 | Fixed the savescreenshot or savescreenshotfull commands to work properly with DPI scaling. |
>
> https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html

Just update your nircmd version and it'll work fine

---

In older versions of nircmd you might still be able to take the real resolution screenshot by disabling scaling in the *Compatibility* tab in the *Properties* dialog of `nircmd.exe`. Change *"Scaling performed by:"* to *"Application"* like below

[image: nircmd properties]

Depending on Windows version the setting may be different but basically it's the same: disable Windows scaling and the application will be rendered at 100%

[image: display display scaling]